# I had a problem when importing the module three.js

Tags: import, module, three.js

> I wrote this thing in my HTML file

```
<script type="module" src="script.js"></script>
```

> And this is the Javascript

```
import * as THREE from 'three';

const scene = new THREE.Scene();
const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000);

const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();

renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

const geometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry(1, 100, 100);
const material = new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial({ color: 0xffffff, roughness: 0.8, metalness: 1});
const ball = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
scene.add(ball);

const light = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff, 1);
light.position.set(0, 10, 10);

scene.add(light);

camera.position.z = 5;

function animate() {
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    ball.rotation.x += 0.01;
    ball.rotation.y += 0.01;
    ball.rotation.z += 0.01;
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
};

animate();
```

> Also the error in the browser console is this

```
Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "three". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".
```

> I tried many times reinstalling the module, even asking chatGPT for help but it also doesn't work. **I BET NO ONE CAN FIX THIS**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing an import map in your code. Add the following above your `<script>` tag.

```html
<script async src="https://unpkg.com/es-module-shims@1.3.6/dist/es-module-shims.js"></script>

<script type="importmap">
  {
    "imports": {
      "three": "https://unpkg.com/three@0.148/build/three.module.js"
    }
  }
</script>
```

This will load `three.js` from a CDN (`unpkg`). However, you can replace the URL with a path to your locally hosted `three.js` version.

Comment: but I've seen no one doing like that

Comment: The official examples use that pattern: https://threejs.org/examples/. It is also explained in the documentation: https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#manual/en/introduction/Installation

Comment: Better to check the official resources first since they are usually up-to-date.